# How to get the attributed string in the NSTextContainer not the NSTextStorage

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsattributedstring, nstextview, nstextcontainer

Good day,

Im trying to get the attributed string for the NSTextContainer not the NSTextStorage, any time I use the method that returns the attributedString of a textView, it returns the attributedString for the NSTextStorage and I just want the attributedString for that bounding rect? Any Suggestions? I've been struggling with this for days.

I'll appreciate any assistance.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe with `glyphRange(forBoundingRect:in:)`? But it's unclear on you retrive the attributedString from the TextContainer...

Comment: How about `glyphRange(for:)`, `characterRange(forGlyphRange:actualGlyphRange:)` and `attributedSubstring(from:)`?